# using 'awk in awk'

Tags: awk, sed

How can I separate below lines with `awk` before ":" until "-"?

```
cat list.txt
domain.com/prod-1/name-1/imagename:1.0.71-b651706b950efc68857089d89ej3423423adfdsf
domain.com/prod02/name-2asd-asdasd-11/imagename1:2.0.71-b651706b950efc68857089dsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf
```

I tried `awk in awk` but no success

```
cat ist.txt |awk -F ":" {'a=$1; b=awk -F "-"{'print $2'};print a b '}
```

Expected result is

```
domain.com/prod-1/name-1/imagename:1.0.71
domain.com/prod02/name-2asd-asdasd-11/imagename1:2.0.71
```

Comment: Does it have to be `awk`?  It looks like `sed` would do the job admirably: `sed 's/^\([^:]*:[^-]*\)-.*/\1/'`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'before ":" until "-"'. From your examples, it looks like you want to remove the last "-" and everything after it. Is that correct? What does ":" have to do with it?

Comment: It depends, @jared_mamrot, on whether there can be extra dashes in the trailing text.  The example input doesn't show any trailing dashes, but then again, the text seems to contain quite a lot of `sdf` characters in sequence, which suggests quasi-random typing on the keyboard rather than genuine data.

Comment: If it's any consolation, the `sed` answer assumes no dashes in the trailing material too.

Comment: Why not `sed 's/-[^-]*$//' list.txt` ?

Comment: May I suggest a more compelling title as well? As far as "awk in awk" goes at getting people's attention, it is by any means not search-friendly nor describes what the issue is: splitting lines with 2 different field separators.

Comment: Calling awk from within awk may have a very, very rare application but this isn't it. In general calling awk from within awk is like if you need more storage space in your kitchen and  you build a new cabinet inside an existing cabinet instead of next to one.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `split()` function to split a string inside `awk`.

```
awk -F':' '{split($2, a, /-/); print $1 ":" a[1]}' ist.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

with `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/(:[^-]*)-.*/\1/' file

domain.com/prod-1/name-1/imagename:1.0.71
domain.com/prod02/name-2asd-asdasd-11/imagename1:2.0.71
```

Comment: I'd be happier if the regex was `s/(:[^-]*)-.*/\1/` — the `.*` is too greedy if there are dashes in the trailing data.  Granted, the example data doesn't contain trailing dashes, but then again, the text seems to contain quite a lot of `sdf` characters in sequence, which suggests quasi-random typing on the keyboard rather than genuine data.

Comment: Modified as @JonathanLeffler suggests so I could upvote as the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using `gensub()` function on GNU `awk`:

```
awk '{print gensub(/(^.*)(-.*$)/,"\\1","g")}' file
domain.com/prod-1/name-1/imagename:1.0.71
domain.com/prod02/name-2asd-asdasd-11/imagename1:2.0.71
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples could you please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk 'match($0,/:[^-]*/){print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                         ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/:[^-]*/){           ##using match function to match everything from : to till - here.
  print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) ##printing everything before RSTART and then printing matched regex value here.
}
' Input_file                  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```